# Samsung Tab 3 drivers reinstallation

Tags: usb-drivers

I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. Upon connecting to the PC, some of its drivers were not installed. I'm using the Tab for the first time. Developer mode/option is checked.

I want to run my apps on it, but it is not recognizing it. So, how do I re-install the drivers?

Comment: Did you try unmounting any storage? **Settings > Storage > [Menu]**: make sure all boxes are unticked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install the [Samsung Android USB Driver for Windows.](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)
   (It's the zip file at the top of the page.)
2. Go to **Settings > Security > Unknown Sources** and check the box.
3. Turn on **USB debugging** in Developer Options.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Samsung Kies](http://content.samsung.com/us/contents/aboutn/kiesIntro.do), and install it. It will install all the drivers you need, plus the Samsung Kies software, where you can do back-ups and other phone management tasks.

Comment: but not work'n ,i'm nt able to run my app through pc

Comment: What do you mean by run my app through PC?

Comment: I believe he means to push an apk from his PC via an IDE, etc

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

- Unmount any USB storage: **Settings > Storage > [Menu] > USB Computer Connection**: make sure all boxes are unticked.
- Ensure that you have enabled USB debugging from **Settings > Developer Options > USB debugging**. After enabling it, you should see an ongoing notification that it is enabled when you connect it to your PC.
- Ensure that you have the latest [Samsung USB drivers for your device](http://androidxda.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers).